# How to fit data to normal distribution using scala breeze

Tags: scala, statistics, breeze, scala-breeze

I am trying to fit data to normal distribution using scala breeze , python scipy alternative way is :

`from scipy.stats import norm`

`mu,std = norm.fit(time1)`

I am looking for alternative way to do same in scala using breeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py) for `norm.fit`, it looks like if you use the function with only the data passed in (ie no other parameters), then this function just returns the mean and standard deviation:. We can accomplish the same in Breeze like so:

```
scala> val data = DenseVector(1d,2d,3d,4d)
data: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)

scala> val mu = mean(data)
mu: Double = 2.5

scala> val samp_var = variance(data)
samp_var: Double = 1.6666666666666667

scala> val n = data.length.toDouble
n: Double = 4.0

scala> val pop_var = samp_var * (n-1)/(n)
pop_var: Double = 1.25

scala> val pop_std = math.sqrt(pop_var)
pop_std: Double = 1.118033988749895
```

We need to modify the sample variance to get the population variance. This is the same as the `scipy` result:

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [2]: mu, std = norm.fit([1,2,3,4])

In [3]: mu
Out[3]: 2.5

In [4]: std
Out[4]: 1.1180339887498949
```

Comment: How is it different from stddev?

Comment: Population variance/stddev vs Sample variance/stddev. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance)